# while downloading a file from a socket method download doesn't finish operating

Tags: java

I am writing a program which is able to move files through a socket using the following methods but when I am downloading a file from the socket method download in client program doesn't end operating and exiting the loop although the upload method in server side has finished operating.
here is my download method in client

```
public synchronized void downloadFile(String url) throws IOException{
        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(url)) {
        int countedBytes;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[kbBlockSize];
        while ((countedBytes = input.read(buffer)) > 0)
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, countedBytes);//end while
        fileOutputStream.flush();
    }//end try with resources block
}//end method downloadFile
```

and here is the uploading method in server side

```
public synchronized void uploadFile(String url) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(url)) {
        int countedBytes;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[kbBlockSize];
        while ((countedBytes = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            output.write(buffer, 0, countedBytes);//end while
        output.flush();
    }//end try with resources block
}//end method uploadFile
```

but as the above method has finished working the download method doesn't

I'd be thankful if anyone could help.

Comment: What are `input` and `output`? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: input is ObjectInputStream for client socket and output is an ObjecOutputStream for server socket

Answer (score 0):

input.read(buffer) will always be more than 0 unless inputstream is closed.
it will block till it has atleast one byte or EOF.

so either the server must close the stream or send the download size separately, like some kind of header.

for example in http one can set content-length or use chunked encoding to signal the data size.

Why do you want to create a new protocol, instead of using something like http or ftp?